# pull only user name and select groups from AD with Power shell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to get all the users in my OU and list only the names of the users that are a member of any group with the word managers in it and list that group or groups they belong to.

So for example

TSmith
Equipment managers
Managers night shift

Bkline
Equipment managers Day Shift

I have been trying to tweak the below script.
The issue is if the user is a member of any group with managers in the name it list everything about that user.  All the groups the last log on time everything in AD.

Thanks so much for any help.

```
  Import-Module ActiveDirectory
  $users = Get-ADUser -searchbase "OU=East,DC=CHM,DC=com" -Filter * -Properties * 
  foreach ( $user in $users ) {
  $user
      $groups = $user | select -ExpandProperty memberof

      if ($groups -match 'manager') {
          $user.samaccountname
          $groups
          }
}
```

Comment: found solution on anoter BB
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Get-ADUser -searchbase "OU=East,DC=CHM,DC=com" -Filter * -Properties *
foreach ($user in $users)
{
foreach ($member in $user.MemberOf)
{
    if ($member -like "*manager*")
    {
        Write-Host "$($user.SamAccountName) - $($member.Substring(3, $member.IndexOf(",") - 3))"
    }
}
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=East,DC=CHM,DC=com" -Search -ResultSetSize $null -Filter * -Properties memberOf | Foreach-Object {

    # extract grouop names and check if they contain the word 'manager'
    $manager = ($_.memberof -replace '^CN=([^,]+),.+$','$1') -like "*manager*"

    if($manager)
    {
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            UserName = $_.SamAccountName
            ManagerGroups = $manager -join ';'
        }   
    }
}
```